# How to export and import type definitions?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've been using TypeScript for a while and the module system continues to be a mystery to me.

I have this type definition file (appComponents.d.ts):

```typescript
/// <reference path="./authentication/API.d.ts"/>

import express = require('express');

declare module appComponents {
    export interface IComponents {
        application: express.Application;
        authenticationService: MyApp.IAuthenticationService;
        // and so on ...
    }
}
```

and this file (index.ts):

```typescript
/// <reference path="./appComponents.d.ts"/>

import express = require('express');
import mssql = require('mssql');

function initComponents(): appComponents.IComponents {

    // Components initialized here ...
}
```

Two questions:

1. Why do I have to use

   `import express = require('express');`

   instead of

   `/// <reference path="./path/to/definitely-typed/express/express.d.ts"/>`

   to avoid `error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'express'.`? After all, this is just a type definition file that generates no JavaScript depending on the types in another type definition file that also generates no JavaScript.
2. Why does `index.ts` cause `error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'appComponents'.`? And when I do this instead:

   `import appComponents = require('./appComponents');`

   why does it cause `error TS2094: The property 'IComponents' does not exist on the value of type 'appComponents'.`?

Using TypeScript 0.9.7.0.

Comment: This is typical issue which i had too, because it's mix of two concepts - native TS module scope export and require js modules integration. I'd suggest to try it without require just to make it clear how it works. Also you may check how scopes work: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf , page 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. ) Why do I have to use

`import express = require('express');`
instead of
`/// <reference path="./path/to/definitely-typed/express/express.d.ts"/>`

Actually you need to use *both*:

```
/// <reference path="./path/to/definitely-typed/express/express.d.ts"/>
import express = require('express');
```

You probably have the reference in `API.d.ts` or simply have `express.d.ts` included in your visual studio project somewhere.

**How it works** : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts#L15 contains `declare module "express" {` This tells typescript what to give  (everything with `export` in this file : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts when someone does `import / require` i.e  `import express = require('express')` These are known as **external modules** in typescript and can be `amd` / `commonjs`

> Why does index.ts cause error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'appComponents'

Because you are declaring an *internal module* and trying to import it as an *external module*.

PS: video about external / internal modules : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

**UPDATE**

> You said that one of my modules in the question is an internal module:

Just FYI: `declare module appComponents {` makes `appComponents` an internal module. You should do `declare module "appComponents" {` if you want to declare an external module and use `import appComponents = require('appComponents');` But don't. Its not what you want.

> Why does index.ts cause error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'appComponents'.?

Because `appComponents.d.ts` does an `import` it too became an external module. You should move `declare module appComponents {` etc. to its own file free of external modules and then use `///<reference`

Comment: Thanks, I've watched your video at least 10 times now, last time was right before I asked this question. Also, I'm using WebStorm, not VS. You said that one of my modules in the question is an internal module, but they both look like external modules to me. That is, they both have top-level `import`s. At least that's my understanding of how to make an external module.

Comment: Thanks @basarat, but I think I'm closer to understanding the problem. I think I've been misusing `.d.ts` files which, I now think, are only useful for declaring type definitions for external **JavaScript** modules. I had all sorts of weird stuff happening, like multiple `interfaces` in a `.d.ts` file and only one being seen by the compiler. So I started declaring one interface per `.ts` file instead of in `.d.ts` files and all my problems went away, with only one new (minor) problem: These interface-only `.ts` files are compiled into empty `.js` files.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems that whatever `.d.ts` files export ends up in the global scope, albeit ambient (i.e. global in TypeScript, but non-existent in JavaScript). However, these global modules are available to some files and not others, perhaps based on compilation order (`/// <reference path="..."` doesn't seem to help). In some cases, I'm having naming collisions with DefinitelyTyped definitions, although they're being reported as symbol not found rather than duplicate identifier. Still confused, but I'm not making my own `.d.ts` files now.

Comment: Bas, I think you've answered the first part, but not the 2nd, which I have now answered. I understand now that the reference tag is only for forcing the compiler to process specific files that *may* not already be on the compiler's to-do list of files to look at, depending on whether or not other files have referenced it earlier. When we `require` a module by its file name, the compiler checks if any `.d.ts` files on its list of files to compile declares a module with the same name as the `require`d module's file, in double quotes, as does `express.d.ts`: `declare module "express" { ... }`

Comment: @SteveTaylor ^ your understanding in your last comment is correct :)

Comment: [The plot thickens...](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2265#CommentContainer1) Apparently `.d.ts` files are appropriate if used correctly and, in fact, are a workaround for the empty `.js` files issue.

Comment: ^ not really a "workaround" More of an intentional feature for "Definition only, filename.definition.ts". You cannot put code in a `d.ts` :)

Comment: Understood, but it should be noted that weird things happen when you put more than one of something in a `.d.ts` and/or explicitly wrap stuff in a module. I looked at the language spec and `.d.ts` files barely get a mention.

Comment: "weird things happen when you put more than one of something in a .d.ts and/or explicitly wrap stuff in a module" Disagree see : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts#L15 all inside an external module def. and https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/chai/chai.d.ts#L7 all inside an internal module def. Curious what weirdness you are seeing though.

Comment: These are type definitions for third party js modules. In these cases, we directly require the js module by name and tsc finds the .d.ts module of the same name. Completely different to defining interface only modules when we *don't* want to require the implementation modules directly, because we instead want to pass objects by their interface type rather than implementation type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what solved my problem (#2):

Don't create `.d.ts` files as a way of separating interface and implementation of classes. Instead, define `interface`s in `.ts` files. When a class and the interface it implements are in different files, `require` the `interface` module from the `class` module. Do this also for interfaces that are not to be implemented by a class, i.e. interfaces used for strong typing of variables.

Example:

```typescript
// IAppComponents.ts

/// <reference path="../DefinitelyTyped/express/express.d.ts"/>

import express = require('express');
import IAuthenticationService = require('./services/IAuthenticationService')

interface IAppComponents {
    application: express.Application;
    authenticationService: IAuthenticationService;
}
export = IAppComponents;
```

```typescript
// IAuthenticationService.ts

import ILoginCallback = require('./ILoginCallback');
import ILogoutCallback = require('./ILogoutCallback');

interface IAuthenticationService {
    login(user: string, pass: string, callback: ILoginCallback) void;
    logout(sessionToken: string, callback: ILogoutCallback): void;
}
export = IAuthenticationService;
```

```typescript
// AuthenticationService.ts

import IAuthenticationService = require('./IAuthenticationService');
import ILoginCallback = require('./ILoginCallback');
import ILogoutCallback = require('./ILogoutCallback');

// We can't import this, because it's a js module with no matching type definition.
var mssql = require('mssql');

class AuthenticationService implements IAuthenticationService {
    login(user: string, pass: string, callback: ILoginCallback): void {
        // Implementation goes here ...
    }

    logout(sessionToken: string, callback: ILogoutCallback): void {
        // Implementation goes here ...
    }
}
export = AuthenticationService;
```

This approach works, with one tiny caveat: The TypeScript compiler generates `.js` files for each `.ts` (but not `.d.ts`) file, even if the `.ts` file contains only interfaces, resulting in empty `.js` files being generated. I can live with that for now, but I hope the TypeScript team does something about it one day.